# After making a notification in calendar I received an email but I did not get the pop-up

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I made a reminder in calendar about my work. In notification I have checked the notification by email and notification by pop-up (for the same time). Later (after the notification time), when I signed in to my account, I found an email from “Google calendar” but there was no pop-up.

Kindly suggest me some way by which I can get the pop-ups later when I sign in to my account even after the notification time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t. You have to have your Calendar/Gmail browser tab/window open to receive the pop-up notifications.

> To get notifications on your computer, you need to have Google Calendar open in a web browser tab or window.

[Source](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242) (under *Change your default notification settings* → *Computer*).

Comment: Strange. The note about needing to have Google Calendar open in a web browser to receive notifications was removed sometime after November 17, 2017 ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20171117152007/https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242)). But, in my my testing, the need still exists.